# Germany speed limit „bei Nässe“ („by wetness“). Does snow count as wet?

Tags: germany, driving

In early April 2022, I was driving a car on a German motorway somewhere near the border between Hessen and Rheinland-Pfalz.  The local speed limit was 100 km/h, with an additional speed limit 80 km/h *bei Nässe* (literally: „by wetness“), meaning [when there is a layer of water on the road](https://www.adac.de/verkehr/recht/verkehrsvorschriften-deutschland/tempolimit-nasse-strasse/).  It was freezing and lightly snowing at the time, but the snow did not stick to the road.  I was driving around 95 km/h (like everybody else) and, when passing a static radar speed gun, saw a white flash indicative of a photograph being taken, suggesting I may have passed a speed limit and might expect a fine.

I was surprised, because air and road weren't wet; it was snowing, and I don't think snow is wet.  Does traffic law enforcement consider snow as wet?
There is a long discussion [on this forum at verkehrsportal.de](http://www.verkehrsportal.de/board/index.php?showtopic=89091), but it seems everyone is speculating and nobody knows the answer.

During a charging break soon after the photograph was taken, I noticed that my front license plate was obscured by snow (so were all others), for which there is apparently a [€5 fine](https://kennzeichen.express/kfz-kennzeichen-unlesbar-durch-schmutz-und-schnee) — so *perhaps* the flash was not due to speeding but due to an obscured license plate (they can probably still tell the car through the *Umweltplakat*).  So far, I have not received any letter for any fine.

Comment: If the snow didn't stick top the ground, presumably it was melting, and making the ground wet.

Comment: Your link (my German needed some Google help which I've quoted here) says "A roadway is therefore wet if a layer of water, albeit a thin one, has formed on the surface, i.e. the entire roadway is covered with a film of water - no matter how thin it is" but then says "On the other hand, if the road surface is only damp, you do not have to observe the speed limit. A wet road can usually be recognized by the fact that its surface has turned dark." - but you don't need a continuous layer enough to cause spray for the road to look darkened, just a layer on each stone...

Comment: ...so "damp" would appear to be a very narrow band, enough to mean that you don't have to hit the brakes at the first drop of rain.

Comment: A road with water and/or ice on it, at a temperature near freezing, is likely to be slicker than one that is considerably above or below freezing.  If the criteria for "wet" don't take this fact into account, it would seem to defeat the purpose of having a lower speed limit for wet conditions.  (That is, a wet road at 10°C is probably less dangerous than a road with melting snow on it at 1°C or 0°C.)

Comment: the question here is more if there were a dry lane on the road or not. "Bei Nässe" applies only when the whole road is covered, if there is even a tiny dry lane, it doesnt apply.
And as far as I know, the flash light of the speed cams is red / orange. So if you have seen a white light, it could be something else.

Comment: @Dirty-flow I wonder if/how they monitor the state of the road to decide whether to flash at drivers passing by…

Comment: @ChrisH-UK Not necessarily; a thin dry powder can also be pushed away by passing cars immediately.

Comment: @phoog I believe the motivation for the lower speed limit is about aqua-planing, not about slippery surfaces.

Comment: @gerrit it will melt when crushed though, and given the shape of car wheels, some will be crushed even if most is blown away.  Also you say early April, and looking at climate data such a light powder is unlikely - it's too warm. But what were the snow conditions on the day

Comment: @phoog Not necessarily. Special speed limits for wet roads are in Germany usually used where the road surface may not be able to drain (enough) water properly, e.g. around depressions in the terrain into which water can flow and cause a buildup of a thicker layer of water on the road. The problem is not per se that a wet road can be slick, but in those areas, the risk for aquaplaning is considered much higher and driving into a puddle at high speed can cause immediate loss of control of your vehicle. Driving on a consistent layer of ice or snow is much more predictable.

Comment: These signs are also used in places where aqua planing is impossible, e.g. on a steep slope with traffic lights at the lower end.

Comment: @ChrisH-UK I found a few sites indicating an average low temperature of 6°C, but looking at actual records for April 2022, I see a range of low temperatures between -3°C and 10°C.

Comment: @phoog exactly - mostly just around freezing when snow tends to be wet and either stick to things or melt.  That correlates with the obscured numberplate too

Comment: @phoog: "If the criteria for "wet" don't take this fact into account, it would seem to defeat the purpose of having a lower speed limit for wet conditions" – You cannot make a specific law for every possible situation. That's why there are rules such as §1,I StVO ("participating in traffic requires constant vigilance and mutual care"), §1,II StVO ("Who participates in traffic must behave in such a manner that no other is injured, put in danger, or […]"), and §3,I(1) StVO ("Whoever operates a vehicle must limit the speed such that the vehicle is always under their control").

Comment: The snow was wet enough, but I didn't think the road was wet.

Comment: @gerrit how could a road covered in wet snow not itself be wet?

Comment: @phoog It didn't cover the road.  It was light snowfall.  From the linked source, the _by Nässe_ sign is about a road covered in water and the speed limit of 80 km/h is related to the physics of aqua-planing. A few droplets apparently do not count as a wet road. Of course, if the road is icy, then driving fast is dangerous, but I didn't think this was the case (by German standards, 95 km/h is quite slow…)

Comment: @gerrit in my experience "snow did not stick to the road" when the temperature is around freezing means that the snow is melting on the road. It wasn't clear to me from the question that the volume of snow was as low as I gather from your comment that it must have been. I suppose it could also describe light snow that was not melting but not accumulating because of wind. The statement "I don't think snow is wet" led me to think that this was a pedantic argument based on the nature of snow (and is difficult to reconcile with "the snow was wet enough").  I now suspect that that's not true.

Comment: "Umweltplakat" - it's "Umweltplakette", not that this is relevant to the question ("Plakat" is a big poster, "Plakette" is a sticker).

Answer (score 4):

*Wetness* does not comprise all kinds of precipitation.

- There are [separate signs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bildtafel_der_Verkehrszeichen_in_der_Bundesrepublik_Deutschland_seit_2017) for snowfall (268), for black ice (<s>1007‑30</s>, 101‑51), for fog (1007‑61), smoke (1007‑31), and for “wetness” (1053‑35).
  The legislation therefore *distinguishes* between those states.
- The entire street needs be covered by a layer of liquid water.
  Puddles or other patches of wetness do not matter.
  (German Federal supreme court decision of 1977‑12‑20, [4 StR 560/77](https://dejure.org/dienste/vernetzung/rechtsprechung?Gericht=BGH&Datum=20.12.1977&Aktenzeichen=4%20StR%20560%2F77))
- The road condition must be recognizable from the driver’s seat.
  Either it’s currently raining so the windshield is covered by (liquid) water, or there are other indications of the previously mentioned criterion.

I don’t think the speed traps are “smart” enough to determine partially obscured license plates or even wetness.
The electric circuits simply measure the speed of any moving object in front of them and exceeding the limit releases the shutter.
There’s usually an orange color filter in front of the flashlight so it doesn’t dazzle drivers (at night).

Comment: Great answer!  Could you add some sources?  Are there traffic signs for explicitly lower speed limits in case of snowfall, black ice, or fog (apart from generic "drive safely" rules)?

Comment: Germany’s traffic administration’s creativity is unlimited, yet (currently) “when wet” is the only conditional weather-related sign that can be combined with a posted speed limit.

Comment: “When wet” can actually be combined with _any_ reasonable sign, apparently even with “slippery road” (sign 114) as I saw today. Well, duh! “Slippery when wet.” This is so German. To be fair, it was on a serpentine road. I also saw “no overtaking when wet” (sign 276).